# Apache sever, deny all except one file plus rewrite condition

Tags: apache

I am trying to deny entire folder, but still have one (several) redirects working

```php
    <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/ssl">
        order deny,allow
        deny from all
    </Directory>
```

Now when points to /ssl/config I want a redirect to /ssl/config.json file

```php
    <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/ssl/config">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        FallbackResource "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/ssl/config.json"
    </Directory>
```

Not working :(
Any clues? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  Fallback Resource is a file, located in the dir with full restriction `Deny from all`. Like this your `config.json` is restricted, also.

You have to extend the rules for the dir `${INSTALL_DIR}/www/ssl` :

```php
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/ssl">
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    <Files "config.json">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

*Please Note:  These "Allow/Deny"-rules are depreciated. You should use the new "Require"-rules.*